# examples of space of direction at a point in an infinite dim Alexandrov space compact

Tags: alexandrov-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

The space of direction at a point in an infinite dim Alexandrov space can be compact?Please give examples or prove it's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the space of direction of an infinite dim Alexandrov space can be compact at some point.

Take for example the pyramid with Hilbert cube as the base.